# error while validating radio button with knockoutjs extend method

Tags: knockout.js

i require an example of validation of implementation with extend in kockoutjs for radio button.
have any body implemented the same. if yes can you please share the example with me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be what you are after.

https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation

Hope this helps.